# How to add SSL certificate to socket connection?

Tags: php, python, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have server written in python3 and client in PHP.
My client can communicate with server but I want to add SSL to this connection.

Why those two scripts below cant communicate with each other?

**server.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import ssl
import socket

ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(purpose=ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
ssl_context.load_verify_locations(capath='.')
sock = socket.socket()
sock = ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock)
sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', 9000))
sock.listen(5)

csock, address = sock.accept()
csock.send(b'Server is listening...')
while True:
    client_msg = csock.recv(256)
    if not client_msg:
        break
    print('Client said: {}'.format(client_msg))
csock.close()

sock.close()
```

**client.php**

```
<?php

$context = stream_context_create([
    'ssl' => [
        'local_cert' => 'test.crt'
    ]
]);

$sock = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://localhost:9000',
    $errno, $errstr,
    30,
    STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT,
    $context
);
fwrite($sock, 'hello from client');
fclose($sock);
```

**test.key and test.crt generation**

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout test.key -out test.crt
```

**Edit**
@syntonym - original error is:

- client.php

  PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): Unable to set private key file `test.crt' in client.php on line 19
  PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto in client.php on line 19
  PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://localhost:9000 (Unknown error) in client.php on line 19
- server.py

  self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:645)

**Edit**
@Deepti
Your answer pushed this problem forward. I added:

```
...
'ssl' => [
    'local_cert' => 'test.crt',
    'local_pk' => 'test.key'
...
```

Now I have errors:

- server.py

  self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  ssl.SSLError: [SSL: NO_SHARED_CIPHER] no shared cipher (_ssl.c:645)
- client.php

  PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
  error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure in client.php on line 15
  PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto in client.php on line 15
  PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://localhost:9000 (Unknown error) in client.php on line 15
  PHP Warning:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in client.php on line 17
  PHP Warning:  fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in client.php on line 18

Comment: What happens? Are error throwns? Does the python server crash? Dos the server reject the connection?

Comment: I've updated question with error messages.